# automatically refreshing child related list after saving a list

Tags: visualforce, trigger, related-list, refresh

[image]
[image]

When I add new pricing by clicking 'new' button in pricing section,

activities and purchases information also add to the list below.

Right now, when I save new pricing, pricing list updates instantly,

but I have to refresh the page manually to update activities and purchases list.

What would be the best way to update all three lists instantly when I save new pricing?

here is the trigger

```
trigger PricingTrigger on Pricing__c (after insert, after update, before delete) {


if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        PricingTriggerHandler.handleBeforeDelete(Trigger.old);      
    }
}
else {
    //Add
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        PricingTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new);      
    }
    //Update
    else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
        PricingTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);    
    }
}
```

}

Here is the part of the trigger controller class

```
 public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Pricing__c> pricings) {
    List<Id> pricingIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Pricing__c pricing : pricings){
        // Only if record is submitted
        if ( pricing.Trigger_Enabled__c == true ){            
            pricingIds.add(pricing.Id);
        }

    }
    addActivitiesPurchasesAndTotalPrice(pricingIds);
}

public static void handleAfterUpdate(List<Pricing__c> oldPricings, List<Pricing__c> newPricings) {
    updateActivitiesPurchasesAndTotalPrice(oldPricings, newPricings);
}

public static void handleBeforeDelete(List<Pricing__c> pricings) {
    deleteActivitiesPurchasesAndTotalPrice(pricings);
}


    public static void addActivitiesPurchasesAndTotalPrice(List<Id> pricingIds) {

    for(Id pricingId : pricingIds){
        //Retrieve Pricing and Reservation
        Pricing__c newPricing = [SELECT Id, Name, Item__c, Pricing_Lookup__c, Quantity__c, Reservation__c, Subtotal__c, Unit_Price__c, Package_Unit_Price__c FROM Pricing__c WHERE Id = : pricingId];
        newPricing.Package_Unit_Price__c = newPricing.Unit_Price__c;
        update newPricing;

        Id reservationId = newPricing.Reservation__c;

        //Reservation that will be updated
        Reservation__c reservation = [SELECT Id, Name, Arrival_Date__c, Departure_Date__c, Date_Received__c FROM Reservation__c where Id =: reservationId];    
        String priceLookupId = newPricing.Pricing_Lookup__c;
        update reservation;

        Pricing_Lookup__c priceLookup = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricing_Lookup__c WHERE Id = : priceLookupId ];

        //Add Activities and Purchases
        addActivityAndPurchasesByPricingLookupId(newPricing, pricingId, reservationId, reservation.Arrival_Date__c, priceLookupId);

        //Update Total
        List<Pricing__c> reservationPricingList = [SELECT Id, Name, Item__c, Pricing_Lookup__c, Quantity__c, Reservation__c, Subtotal__c, Unit_Price__c, Package_Unit_Price__c FROM Pricing__c WHERE Reservation__c = : reservation.Id];
        updateReservationTotalByReservationAndPricings(reservation, reservationPricingList);
    }
}
```

addActivityAndPurchasesByPricingLookupId inserts activity and purchase list....

thank you guys